# Book about a teen girl in a love triangle with the angel of death and a boy who hunts angels

Tags: story-identification, novel

I think I read this as an eBook in the last five years, checked out from the library, and the memories are far more fleeting than I was expecting. Bits that I recall:

- She was saved from dying by the angel. I don't remember if it was because she wasn't supposed to die yet, or because he'd fallen for her. I think she actually died and he brought her back. I want to say that it involved a truck hitting her.
- She was already orphaned, I think living with her grandparents.
- The angel had recently shown up as a transfer student at the school, and I'm pretty sure there were descriptions by the narrator of his flawless beauty and how all of the girls were already after him.
- I think the book was set in the Southwest, with descriptions of the landscape often involving talking about the bare rock and the heat.
- The second boy is known as a troublemaker in school, prone to fights and truancy. I think she learns that it's because he awoke to his heritage as a mystical protector. Around the time she learns this, she also finds out that he lives on his own in his house, although that's not common knowledge.
- There's a plot point where one of the teachers at her school (the principal?) recognizes the angel due to him being involved in an accident involving the teacher's sister when they were younger. There might have been an old photo that made the resemblance unmistakable.
- There was, of course, a love triangle, with her being drawn to both of the boys, both of whom insisted that the other was dangerous, and no good for her.
- They were all about high-school age; can't remember ethnicity.
- I don't remember any sex involved in the plot, and the violence I remember was non-graphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this ***[Death and the Girl Next Door](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12986492-death-and-the-girl-next-door)*** (2012) by Darynda Jones, the first book in the *[Darklight](https://www.goodreads.com/series/69365-darklight)* trilogy...?

[image: Front cover of "Death and the Girl Next Door" (2012) by Darynda Jones.]

According to this [review](https://smexybooks.com/2012/10/review-death-and-the-girl-next-door-by-darynda-jones.html), the protagonist, Lorelei McAlister, is a high school sophomore who's lived with her grandparents since her parents disappeared a decade ago. She finds herself being stalked by an antisocial bad boy named Cameron around the same time that a handsome new student named Jared shows up at her school. The two boys apparently know and dislike one another.

> **Lorelei MacAlister is your average high school sophomore. She has lived with her grandparents since her parents mysteriously disappeared ten years ago.** She’s always had “visions” but they make no sense until she accidentally brushes against a dark handsome young man. **Things turn surreal when antisocial bad boy Cameron Lusk suddenly begins to stalk Lorelei and the dark handsome young man shows up at her school as new student-Jared Kovach. The two boys seem to know each other and the animosity rolls off them, igniting the air, with Lorelei stuck in the middle.** As Lorelei learns the reason behind their hatred for one another, she finds herself connected to both of them in ways she never imagined.

This [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/453467974) mentions that Jared is a transfer student who saves Lorelei from a fatal collision with a bus.

> Small town girl, Lorelei, is about to get a crash course in all things angelic when **she is saved from a fatal collision with a bus by the sexy new transfer student, Jared Kovach.**

This [Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2O7FZ2V6DE1HW/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0312625200) mentions that Jared is Azrael, the Angel of Death, who was sent to cause her death, not prevent it.

> When Jared saves Lorelei from being killed by a hit and run driver, the course of history changes. **Jared is better known as Azrael, the Angel of Death,** and he was sent to cause her death, not prevent it. However, something about her, draws him and makes him give up what he should do to preserve her life.

This [review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/darynda-jones/death-and-girl-next-door/) mentions that Lorelei's school is in New Mexico, that Jared is amazingly gorgeous, and that Cameron is actually stalking Jared, not Lorelei, in an attempt to protect her.

> **Lorelei does well in school until she meets the amazingly gorgeous Jared. She can’t believe he seems attracted to her instead of all the really pretty girls in her small-town New Mexico high school. Meanwhile, she worries about Cameron, another hunky student, who appears to be stalking her. It turns out that Cameron is stalking Jared, however, in an attempt to protect Lorelei.**

This [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/414424988) suggests that Lorelei was hit by a truck (rather than a bus) in the beginning and that Cameron is actually a Nephilim.

> There were also some things that went unexplained until a few chapters later. I can't really mention them all without giving away tons of spoilers. For example, **Lorelei being hit by a truck in the beginning. I had no idea of what was going on. One second, she was being shoved by the kid on the skateboard, and the next she's in pain.** I didn't figure it out until a while later, when it was voiced what had happened. Another thing was, **the whole "Cameron of Jophiel" thing. The concept of Nephilim and the other types of angels wasn't really explained when first brought up. Luckily, I already knew what Nephilim were, so I could infer a lot. But still, for someone who had no idea what they were, this book would be very frustrating.**

Comment: That looks extremely likely! And, with the name in hand, it looks like I read that in September of 2020. Thank you.